# Mouse dragger on keyboard in android

Tags: android

I need to create a keyboard .when i drag over keyboard,a highlighted  pointer should move according to its position on keys.How could i do that?Coding is much better for me.Thanks.

Comment: Are you developing a keyboard?
Do you mean previewing keys in keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

http://organicandroid.blogspot.com/2010/08/starting-to-play-with-graphics.html

this link will tell you how to refresh a view or 2d moving drawing using canvas , thread and all

Comment: Thanx for ur reply javanator.But im not doing 2danimation like that.i need to create a keyboard.from that,when i drag over keyboard,a cursor should move along my path.Using this i can able to select a key.Got it?How could i do that..

Comment: brother i didnt gave you the link for doing animation but to extract information of drawing moving objects on to the screen using touch..which is done in that,...Using thread a view on a canvas can be draw continuously with changing coordinate.. if you will follow the all tutorial in the link ... you will catch the concept...
Your Entire Kyboard and the cursor can be draw using this..
Try This if you need more help i will give you some more reference